# PDF file encryption and decryption in python with fernet key

Tags: python, pdf, encryption, cryptography, fernet

I'm trying to encrypt the pdf file and then trying to decrypt to get its data with fernet key.
i'm able to encrypt it successfully but while decrypting it, i'm getting a binary stream not the actual data, please help. (assume all the needed modules are imported and pdf as data as Hi, how are you in 2 lines)
**Encryption:**

```
def encrypt_file(file_path,file_name):
    try:
        fernet=Fernet(fernet_key)
        print("Created fernet object")
        file=os.path.join(file_path,file_name)
        with open(file,'rb') as f:
            data=f.read()
        try:
            data_enc=fernet.encrypt(data)
        except Exception as e:
            e_msg="".join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))
            print("An occured during data encryption, reason: "+str(e)+"Error: "+e_msg)
            return False
        with open(file,'wb') as f:
            f.write(data_enc)
        print("Encryption Successful")
    except Exception as e:
        print("An occured while encrypting the file, reason: "+str(e)+"Error: "+e_msg)
        return False
    return True
```

**Decryption:**

```
def decrypt_data(file_path,file_name):
    try:
        data=''
        fernet=Fernet(fernet_key)
        file=os.path.join(file_path,file_name)
        with open(file,'rb') as f:
            data_enc=f.read()
        try:
            data=fernet.decrypt(data_enc)
            data=data.decode()
        except Exception as e:
            e_msg="".join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))
            print("An occured during data decryption, reason: "+str(e)+"Error: "+e_msg)
    except Exception as e:
        e_msg="".join(traceback.format_exception(*sys.exc_info()))
        print("An occured while decrypting the file, reason: "+str(e)+"Error: "+e_msg)
        return False

    return data
```

**OUTPUT (trimmed)**
ZxM6cMB3Ou8xWZQ4FpZVUKelqo11TcJr_Js7LFo-0XpU05hsIX0pz88lqEfLmY_TSZQWHuYb1yulBT3FYBTd-QU0RqPlPsCSkH3z_LIHyIie5RO7Rztgxs2Y2zyAzkoNQ9M52hhqNgybTE8K_OzQGb9clOTKdkidCW4VTH77HGbSP1EK-x3lTTmVVf0m-

Comment: Can you encrypt and decrypt a simple text file? Try that, and see if it works. If it doesn't then you have a problem with either encryption of decryption. If it does, then you have a problem with the PDF file. Perhaps you need to check carefully that you are expecting, essentially, a binary file, not some other format, at all stages of the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to encrypt and decrypt a pdf file, you don't need the `data=data.decode()`. Instead, you can write to an output pdf by appending the code below to your `decrypt_data` function.

```
f=open(os.path.join(file_path, "output.pdf"), "wb")
f.write(data)
```

Now if you open `output.pdf`, it will be the decrypted pdf.

If you only want a string with the readable text in the pdf, then it may help to look into pdf reading libraries such as PyPDF2.